# Bootstrap code for attached image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to code the rectangles you can see in attached picture with bootstrap. How would one go about doing so? Should I use images for that or is there a way to code this with CSS. Especially curious am I about, how to create the stacking effect.
Thanks so much for the help.

[example http://harbordev.com/example.png](http://harbordev.com/example.png)

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: I'm fiddeling with it here. http://jsfiddle.net/t222kcgs/

Comment: Try this link Hope it may useful for you http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/05/simple-stack-effects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="rectangle letter">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
         .letter {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  margin: 26px auto 0;
  max-width: 550px;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 24px;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}
.letter:before, .letter:after {
  content: "";
  height: 98%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.letter:before {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  left: 275px;
  top: -295px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.letter:after {
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  right: -275px;
  top: 1px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

 .rectangle {
    margin: 50px;
  background-color: #f89131;
  position: absolute;
  width: 273px;
  height: 273px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.rectangle p {

    padding: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Hope this may useful

Or Here is your Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7478/)

Comment: you are awesome, thanks so much for your help. This is very cool but now the stacking happens all in the same place. I'm trying to diagonal stack them just like in the picture. Do you have an idea for that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7476/  I think I"m getting there. But it's not very elegant...

Comment: In my pc your image is not rendering Laura, pls try to show me in any other link

Comment: harbordev.com/example.png

Comment: I edited my code, pls check it out Laura

Comment: I Hope this answer will be useful for you, If your problem is solved means pls tick my answer Laura

Answer (score 0):

How about this

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/q9n1nkwb/)

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='row'>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Something</span>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background:#aeaeae;
}
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li, .row {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:white;
    margin:5px;
}
li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear:both;
}
.row {
    background:none;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    display:inline-block;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:relative;
}
ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.wrapper {
    margin-left:50px;
}
li:hover {
    background:purple;
}
li:hover span {
    color:white;
}
li {
    text-align:center;
}
li span {
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:40px;
}
```